# JAVA MYsql login form - login function does not work properly ( Javafx)

Tags: java, sql, validation, authentication, javafx

here is my code for the method that I created for my login form.
Everytime "login failed " message commes up even if I entered correct username and password.
What can be wrong here.

```
 public class Controller {
        @FXML
        private Button cancelbutton;
        @FXML
        private Label loginmessagelabel;
        @FXML
        private PasswordField password1;
        @FXML
        private TextField username1;
        PreparedStatement pst;
        ResultSet rs;

    public void validatelogin() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/medibase";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "0852";
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL,username,password);
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        pst=connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user_account WHERE username=? and password=?");
        pst.setString(1, String.valueOf(username1));
        pst.setString(2, String.valueOf(password1));
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            loginmessagelabel.setText("Congratulations");
        } else{
            loginmessagelabel.setText("Login failed");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake and fixed it
here are the changes that I made.

```
  String uname = username1.getText();
    String psd = password1.getText();
    pst=connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user_account WHERE 
    username=? and password=?");
    pst.setString(1, uname);
    pst.setString(2, psd);
```

I took separate variables and assigned the vales form the textboxes by useing getText() method.

Comment: To be more specific, the mistake was doing `String.valueOf(username1)`. That ultimately calls `TextField#toString()` which is not what you want. You need the text that the user typed, not the string representation of the object. To get the text you need to call `TextField#getText()`. Note you can still do this inline if you want: `pst.setString(1, username1.getText());`. Same for the password.